# how to design a new string match algorithm by java

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a java library or tool that can work with the following requirement.

give a string :

```
"how are you doing today"
```

the character "*" match all words, "+" match one word.

here are some patterns and result:

```
"how * today"    --> return true
"how * tomorrow"    --> return false
"how + + + today"   --> return true
"how + + today"   --> return false
```

ps: I don't want to use regex,  can't pre-compile the pattern and only support "*" and "+".

the reason why I don't want to pre-compile it, because the pattern should not be stored in local memory(will cause OutOfMemoryException someday), there are millions of patterns there and will grow day by day. I consider to store the pattern in remote cache like redis. I will get all patterns from redis then compare them with the input string.

The pattern will be configured by users who are not a developer

Comment: Since you are saying that no regex can satisfy your performance requirements can you please clearly specify what are your performance requirements?

Comment: You can split sentence with blank and you can check requirements but there are several problems come here, what if user press multiple blank instead of just one, or what happens when you enters how you today and how * + today? Is this something you want. In my opinion, you can and should use regex to handle this.

Comment: You could replace + by \w+ (probably also add ^ at start and $ at end) and use regex. Would be the simplest solution, even though it is not what you want.

Comment: Regex is complex to "them", but not for you. So convert their pattern to regex. Or as Karol said, explain why exactly is regex "too slow" for you.

Comment: Note that requests for external tools or libraries are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). `can't pre-compile the pattern` Please give the cause of this. Please state more clearly if there is *the one string* and "plenty of query strings pertaining to *the one string*". Not *specifying* a pattern using any of the "well-known" regex syntaxes needing *a simpler user-interface* on one hand and *not using `java.util.regex`* on the other are very much independent issues.

Comment: Thanks for adding that you batch process `millions of patterns with the number growing …`. You still don't state unambiguously whether 1) these patterns are semi-static 2) the item that changes from query to query is `the input string`. The standard approach to handling more data than comfortably handled `in local memory` is to use a database engine. That said, a data structure like, e.g., a [Trie](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) *may* be significantly smaller than the accumulated size of all `pattern`. Please specify in more detail the result required: will a map *pattern id* -> t/f do?